# Sharing Between Operators in DAG

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

Say I have a DAG with dag_id as run_id and the pipeline is T1 > T2 > T3 where T1,T2,T3 are Python operators.

I want to be able to pass parameters from T1 into T2 *without* storing them in a database/S3 and reading them back into T2, as this is long.

I know if T1 fails then T2 won't execute and looking into this I saw that the decision is based on exit code (0/1) so there doesn't seem to be a way to pass parameters through.

Does anyone know if I can pass parameters / output to the next operator without reading/writing externally? Are there any examples of this as I could not find any.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in documentation of airflow you can use Xcoms. XComs let tasks exchange messages, allowing more nuanced forms of control and shared state. The name is an abbreviation of “cross-communication”. XComs are principally defined by a key, value, and timestamp, but also track attributes like the task/DAG that created the XCom and when it should become visible. Any object that can be pickled can be used as an XCom value, so users should make sure to use objects of appropriate size. Check this link:https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms

Say T1 has task id t1 and calls python function **func**.

```
def func():
    return some_value
```

You can fetch the return value of **func** using xcom.
Say T2 calls some python function **sample_function**. Then you can fetch **func** return value as

```
def sample_function(**context):
    value = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='t1')
```

Note, you need to pass context in your function, this can be done by mentioning `provide_context=True` in operator.

Comment: Xcoms is for variables, which is no good for this case, as you still need to write the data first.